# if condition to limit the words in wordpress title

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written this code to loop through the latest 6 posts on my blog and display them in a special box but there is a slight problem, when i write longer titles the title moves to the next line. I cant increase the width of my title div so I need to write an if condition to show a "..." if the title moves to the next line after lets say 20 characters.

```
<div id="freshlyWrapper">
<div id="freshlyposts">
<?php
$freshlyIonised = new WP_Query();
$freshlyIonised->query('category_name=FreshlyIonised&showposts=6');
while($freshlyIonised->have_posts()):
$freshlyIonised->the_post();
?>
<div class="freshlyionisedbox"><h3><a style='text-decoration: underline; color: #000;' href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$title = get_the_title();

if (strlen($title) > 20)
    $title = substr( $title, 0 , 20 ) . "..."; // Limits title to 20 characters.
```

Implement like so:

```
<div id="freshlyWrapper">
<div id="freshlyposts">
<?php
    $freshlyIonised = new WP_Query();
    $freshlyIonised->query('category_name=FreshlyIonised&showposts=6');
    while($freshlyIonised->have_posts()):
        $freshlyIonised->the_post();

        $title = get_the_title();

        if (strlen($title) > 20)
            $title = substr( $title, 0 , 20 ) . "..."; // Limits title to 20 characters.
?>
<div class="freshlyionisedbox">
    <h3><a style='text-decoration: underline; color: #000;' href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a></h3>
```

Comment: `the_title()` echoes the title... `get_the_title()` returns it.

Comment: @Chase thanks for your reply, but Im kinda new to wordpress and php so can u please tell me where to put this code? Sorry this is really a noob question but I have tried putting it everywhere i thought it would work but it seems it doesnt.

Comment: @Sheikh I updated my answer to be included in your code snippet.

Comment: @Chase thank you so much, works beautifully. Everybody else who answered this question, thank you!

Comment: @Chase, could you look into another matter. I have developed this website www.ionisedmesh(.)com from the toolbox theme in wordpress. The problem is that every link in this theme is blue and is underlined. I have gone through the css but couldnt find anything that was setting the links to blue. Could you be so kind to point where the problem is? I would like the links to be black and not underlined. Even the disqus section has become blue and underlined.

Comment: @Chase, the homepage's title shows "Ionised Mesh | Ionised Mesh". I would like that to be just "Ionised Mesh". heres the header code: <title><?php
 /*
  * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
  */
 global $page, $paged;

 wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
bloginfo( 'name' );
$site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
echo " | $site_description";
if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'toolbox' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
?></title>

Comment: @Sheikh Hyperlinks are blue/underlined by default. You may need to add CSS to make them black and not underlined.

Comment: @Sheikh As for the title, try removing the code before `bloginfo('name')`, then you should only see *Ionised Mesh* for the page title.

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way, with CSS:

```
DIV.freshlyionisedbox {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

The advantage of this being the semantic content of your page is preserved, and you don't have to guess at how many characters will fit on the user's screen in a certain number of pixels.

Comment: Never knew that existed. Thanks! There's a workaround for Firefox here: http://sharonminsuk.com/blog/2010/07/22/css3-text-truncation-and-ellipses-even-in-firefox-and-without-the-styling-constraints/

Answer (score 2):

The [substr](http://php.net/substr) way:

```
$title = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
echo strlen($title) > 25 ? substr($title, 0, 25).'...' : $title;
// The quick brown fox jumpe...
```

This is what I usually use, to prevent words from cutting:

```
function truncate($str, $width, $cutword = false) {
    if (strlen($str) <= $width) return $str;
    list($out) = explode("\n", wordwrap($str, $width, "\n", $cutword), 2);
    return $out.'...';
}

$title = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
echo truncate($title, 25); 
// The quick brown fox...

$title = "The quick brown fox";
echo truncate($title, 25); 
// The quick brown fox
```

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
$title = get_the_title();
if (strlen($title) > 20) $title = substr($title, 0, 17) . "...";
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need condition, apply this

```
echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 20, '...');
```